# Kendo-UI assign template values to MVVM, which is not a property of the binded the Datasource

Tags: mvvm, data-binding, kendo-ui, kendo-mvvm, kendo-template

can you tell me how to assign a value of a dynamic amount of forms with input-field to a MVVM-Property in a template. The examples of the official Documentation is always binding to a property to the binded dataSource. I don't want to use the datasource properties, because ill have a more complex datasource, so i don't want to send the whole object to the server, only the entered Values! I want to it Like this:

```
<div id="example" data-template="template" data-bind="source: arr"></div>

<script id="template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div>
        <div> Age: ${age}</div>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: inputs"/>
        <h1 data-bind="text: inputs"></h1>
        <span data-bind="click: show">click</span>
    </div>
</script>

var arr = new kendo.data.ObservableArray([
    { name: "John Doe", age: 23 }, 
    { name: "Jane Doe", age: 34 }
]);

var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    arr: arr ,
    inputs:"asdas",
    show: function(){alert(viewModel.get('inputs'));}

});

kendo.bind($("#example"), viewModel);
```

You will see that the inputs property don't get the entered value. What is the correct way to do it?

Thank

Comment: They are working fine. check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/iamsalik/pk7jr1x1/ If your requirement is different then explain it further

Answer (score 0):

Here is your updated code

```
<div id="example" data-template="template" data-bind="source: arr"></div>

<script id="template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div>
        <div> Age: ${age}</div>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: name"/>
        <h1 data-bind="text: name"></h1>
        <span data-bind="click: show">click</span>
    </div>
</script>

var arr = new kendo.data.ObservableArray([
    { name: "John Doe", age: 23 }, 
    { name: "Jane Doe", age: 34 }
]);

var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    arr: arr ,
    inputs:"asdas", // Binding with this is also working
    show: function(e){alert(e.data.name);}

});

kendo.bind($("#example"), viewModel);
```

Working in this fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/iamsalik/pk7jr1x1/1/